# Error with v-bind in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I try get data from my API server with `axios` but i get this error:

```
'v-bind' directives require an attribute value.
```

I dont know how i must use `v-bind` to fix it.
Here is my code :

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="title"><span>Fetured Items</span><br>
    <span>Shop for items based on what we featured in this week</span></p>
    <div v-if="products && products.length" class="content">
      <content-item v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"
      v-bind:name="product.name"
      v-bind:price="product.price"
       v-bind:srcToProdImage= 'localhost:8081/' + product.productImage></content-item>
    </div>
    <p class="cont-btn">
      <button class="btn">Browse All Product <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Content_item from './Content-item';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data:{
    products,
    errors
  },
  created(){
    axios.get('localhost:8081/products')
    .then((result) => {
      this.products = result.data.products
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.errors.push(err)
    });
  },
  components: {
    'content-item' : Content_item
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  span:first-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  span:last-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #9f9f9f;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
.cont-btn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn{
  padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;
  background-color: #f16d7f;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Err:
[image]

Comment: This `v-bind:srcToProdImage= 'localhost:8081/' + product.productImage` is invalid.

Comment: You could use a computed which returns the expected url and use the computed as the bind value.

Answer (score 8):

Just put double quotes around your `srcToProntImage` expression:

```
<content-item v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"
      v-bind:name="product.name"
      v-bind:price="product.price"
       v-bind:srcToProdImage="'localhost:8081/' + product.productImage"></content-item>
```

Comment: Thank you.But I get another error.I update question.

Comment: A bit of explanation - vue is trying to evaluate the expression assigned to `v-bind:whatever` so you need the quotes around your string since `localhost:8081/ + someVar` in javascript would also throw an exception.

Comment: you need to update the data function: `products: [], errors: []`

Answer (score 1):

You may have some **syntax error**. Please check if there is some <, > , or exstra " characters in your Vue related codes. This was the error in my case.